# Refresh token feature

Tags: spartacus-storefront

how can i make refresh token feature work? 
I don't see refresh token in local storage, and it is because core doesn't have it in storemodule config

```
export function authStoreConfigFactory(): StateConfig {
  // if we want to reuse AUTH_FEATURE const in config, we have to use factory instead of plain object
  const config: StateConfig = {
    state: {
      storageSync: {
        keys: {
          'auth.userToken.token.access_token': StorageSyncType.LOCAL_STORAGE,
          'auth.userToken.token.token_type': StorageSyncType.LOCAL_STORAGE,
          'auth.userToken.token.expires_in': StorageSyncType.LOCAL_STORAGE,
          'auth.userToken.token.expiration_time': StorageSyncType.LOCAL_STORAGE,
          'auth.userToken.token.scope': StorageSyncType.LOCAL_STORAGE,
          'auth.userToken.token.userId': StorageSyncType.LOCAL_STORAGE,
        },
      },
    },
  };
  return config;
}
```

What is the correct way to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Refresh token was deliberately omitted in default storage synchronization configuration for security reasons.

However, if you need that you can always provide your own storage synchronization configuration like in the example below. It will not override default configuration, but it will be combined with it. To exclude something from default configuration you can use `excludeKeys` similarly to `keys` property in `storageSync` configuration.

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { translationChunksConfig, translations } from "@spartacus/assets";
import { ConfigModule, StateConfig, StorageSyncType } from "@spartacus/core";
import { B2cStorefrontModule } from "@spartacus/storefront";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

export function refreshTokenConfigFactory(): StateConfig {
  const config: StateConfig = {
    state: {
      storageSync: {
        keys: {
          "auth.userToken.token.refresh_token": StorageSyncType.LOCAL_STORAGE
        }
      }
    }
  };
  return config;
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    B2cStorefrontModule.withConfig({
      backend: {
        occ: {
          baseUrl: "http://localhost:9002",
          prefix: "/rest/v2/"
        }
      },
      context: {
        baseSite: ["electronics-spa"]
      },
      i18n: {
        resources: translations,
        chunks: translationChunksConfig,
        fallbackLang: "en"
      },
      features: {
        level: "1.5",
        anonymousConsents: true
      }
    }),
    ConfigModule.withConfigFactory(refreshTokenConfigFactory),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```