# Spartacus logging out the application without considering the refresh token

Tags: spartacus-storefront

In my application accessTokenValiditySeconds=10 and refreshTokenValiditySeconds=2592000. But after 10 seconds the application is logging out without considering the refresh token. (As per the analysis it is calling revoke method instead of refreshing the access token).

Kindly help me to resolve this.

Comment: I followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60407557/refresh-token-feature now refresh token is working but it is showing "An Unknown authentication error occured" error for every refresh token call. How to resolve this?

Comment: Also, If it exceeds the expires_in time then it is making api call 2 times. One is with the expired token and another one is with the refresh token.

Comment: Which spartacus version are you using?